# Unreal Engine 5 - Fire Particle assets look different when imported in an environment from unreal engine 4

Tags: 3d, unreal-engine4, scene, unreal-engine5

I'm new to using unreal engine so please forgive my ignorance. Currently started and using unreal engine 5

i am Building a medivial scene and i imported the medvial project from unreal engine marketplace (It was made for unreal engine 4, but im using unreal engine 5)

I noticed that after i add a P_Fire asset to the scene, it doesn't actually look like fire, more like a small version of the sun. (Image below)

[image: How it looks in unreal engine 5 (in a village imported from unreal engine 4)]
*How it looks in unreal engine 5 (in a village imported from unreal engine 4)*

This is a stark contrast to how it looks when i import the exact same asset on a brand new project. (Image below)

[image: How it looks in a brand new unreal engine 5 project]
*How it looks in a brand new unreal engine 5 project*

What could i be missing?
Any piece of information or nudge could be a big help. I feel like its something fundamental and i just lack the experience to realise it.

Much appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeah...I also faced this problem some time ago

It occurs mainly due to the new lumen lighting system. My problem was just fixed by tweaking the material and shader setting (luminous intensity)

It appears your particles are just over saturated in luminosity. Maybe this will fix this :

1.go to the material of the particle
2.there will be a option for luminosity
3.lower it

If the lux value it low enough and the particles still seem offset IDK how to fix it. But maybe this video will help u out :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqJm3B8cubo

Particles and water ripple work on the same principle.

They use various normal maps that are scrolled in different directions which the are combined with a fire material to create fire particles.

I hope this helps because I am also not that good at unreal engine. If this is wrong and afterwards you get the answer please share it with me here so I can learn more and if this works please mark this as an answer.